# Transport Data Within TabControls

Tags: c#, winforms, tabpage

I have a `TabControl` with two pages, `tabPage1` and `tabPage2`. Both pages have db connections and actions.

**Question:**

`tabPage1` shows records of users on a `DataGridView` panel (working). I want to be able to click on a record in the `DataGridView` and have the program show the record's detailed information on `tabPage2's` `textBoxes/comboBoxes`.

How can I show the records on `tabPage2` when clicking or double clicking on a row in the `DataGridView`??
(i can achieve this using form pages but not with a `TabControl`)

Comment: WPF, Winforms? The display technology you are using will affect the answer to this quite a bit.

Comment: I tried to make your post a little more readable, feel free to review. I'm not familiar enough with WinFrom DataGridView to help, but I'm sure someone will come along!

Comment: you just want to transfer data from the one page to another page??

Comment: yea, readind datagridview1 on tabPage1 to tabPage2 textbox/combobox

Comment: anybody doesn't know?

Answer (score 0):

Just use the RowEnter event to update the Value of the TextBox:

```
public Form1() {
  InitializeComponent();
  dataGridView1.RowEnter += dataGridView1_RowEnter;
}

void dataGridView1_RowEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) {
  var cellValue = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value;
  if (cellValue != null) {
    textBox1.Text = cellValue.ToString();
  } else {
    textBox1.Text = string.Empty;
  }
}
```

The fact that these controls are in different TabPages shouldn't matter.  If these controls were added in the designer, then you should have direct access to the controls.

If you are adding these controls at run-time, that's a different story...

Comment: thanks but i solved the problem with datagridviews RowHeaderDoubleClick event. i wrote the event tabControl1.selectedPage=tabPage2;   :))

Comment: @paradoxIST You do realize you are talking about code you didn't show us?  Wait, so your question was about switching tabs?